# Webpack import from %appdata%

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, electron

I have an electron app that needs to read a file stored in `%appdata%` (or the equivalent for macOS and linux). I am importing the file like this

```
const appPath = app.getPath("appData");
const data = await import(appPath + "/app/file.json");
```

If I run the code from the source file it works, but when I am trying to bundle it with webpack, I get a `Module not found` error. I know this is caused by webpack trying to perform an analysis on my imports.

So is there a way to import a file dynamically in webpack?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: my webpack config (no babel since I am using typescript)

```
  var path = require("path");
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    output: {
        filename: "main.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    },
    node:{
        __dirname:false
    },
    target: "electron-main",
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ['firebase/app']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.cjs.js'),
            ['firebase']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/firebase/dist/index.node.cjs.js')
        }, extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        noParse: "/public/**/*",
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            // {
            //     test: /\.json$/,
            //     loader: 'json-loader'
            // }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin([
            { from: './src/public', to: './public' }
        ]),
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Share your webpack and babel configurations.

Comment: When does your app need to read this file? When application is running or at the build time?

Comment: At run time. I will try once again using fs,since quite a few people told me,but I am pretty sure fs yielded the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking into documentation it seems the answer is in [Module Methods](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/) section:

> **Dynamic expressions in import()**
>
> It is not possible to use a fully dynamic import statement, such as `import(foo)`. Because `foo` could potentially be any path to any file in your system or project.
>
> The `import()` must contain at least some information about where the module is located. [...]

It is not clear if you need to read it at build time or at runtime, if its the former then make sure to copy the file to working directory (so that file is bundled in the build), if its the latter then you could use `fs` module to get the file at runtime.

Comment: I read that, but I hope there was some workaround since copying the file to the bundle is obviously not an option

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `fs`?

Comment: Alright, so for some reason, it didn't work the first time I used fs. But I guess the problem was somewhere else back then and I hadn't notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try dynamic import and use promises like this

```
import(appPath + "/app/file.json").then(data => {
   console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: I forgot to add the await in the post, but using dynamic import is what I tried doing

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't, but the `NormalModuleRpelacementPlugin` might be a solution for your problem. You can use it in build time, however it could depends the environment for example.

The file path is same in the code, but after the build it will be changed whatever you want.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/

Comment: I looked into it, and it still requires me to  know the path that I want to import from. Since `%appdata%` is in the user folder which can have any name, this won't work